# jQuery - Set and retrieve cookie from select menu

Tags: jquery, select, cookies, js-cookie

I have a select menu that allows you to choose your preferred country of delivery. When you select an option it show the relevant country underneath.

I'm trying to set a cookie using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) so that the last selection is always remembered for the user. Here's what I have so far but it just isn't working:

https://jsfiddle.net/33xfzvg8/11/

```
$('#country').change(function() {
  $('.box').hide();
  var $countrycode = $('#delivery' + $(this).val());
  if( Cookies !== undefined && Cookies.get('deliveryOption') == undefined  ){
    Cookies.set('deliveryOption', $countrycode);
  } else {
    $('#delivery' + $(this).val()).show();
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

I want to store the select option's value as a cookie and then use that same value to show the respective countries information. This is the cookie that currently gets stored, which looks incorrect:

`{%220%22:{%22jQuery112405649891521717818%22:9}%2C%22length%22:1%2C%22context%22:{%22location%22:{%22href%22:%22https://zed-labz.myshopify.com/pages/delivery%22%2C%22ancestorOrigins%22:{}%2C%22origin%22:%22https://zed-labz.myshopify.com%22%2C%22protocol%22:%22https:%22%2C%22host%22:%22zed-labz.myshopify.com%22%2C%22hostname%22:%22zed-labz.myshopify.com%22%2C%22port%22:%22%22%2C%22pathname%22:%22/pages/delivery%22%2C%22search%22:%22%22%2C%22hash%22:%22%22}%2C%22mc-embedded-subscribe-form%22:{%220%22:{}%2C%221%22:{}}}%2C%22selector%22:%22#deliverycountry1%22}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You save a jQuery collection, since *$countrycode* is not the value:

  ```
  var $countrycode = $('#delivery' + $(this).val());
  ```
- There is never a moment you get the value from the cookie to set the selection

Here is corrected code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#country').change(function() {
        $('.box').hide();
        if( Cookies ) {
            Cookies.set('deliveryOption', $(this).val());
        }
        $('#delivery' + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
    });
    // On page load, read out the cookie, and select the corresponding country
    // If no cookie, take country1 as default
    var country = Cookies && Cookies.get('deliveryOption') || 'country1';
    $('#country').val(country).trigger('change');
})
```

See it in [the corrected fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33xfzvg8/13/).